# How to check if a symlink exists

Tags: bash, symlink

I'm trying to check if a symlink exists in bash. Here's what I've tried.

```
mda=/usr/mda
if [ ! -L $mda ]; then
  echo "=> File doesn't exist"
fi


mda='/usr/mda'
if [ ! -L $mda ]; then
  echo "=> File doesn't exist"
fi
```

However, that doesn't work. 
If '!' is left out, it never triggers. And if '!' is there, it triggers every time.

Comment: for what its worth, if you use [[ ! -D $mda ]] works just fine..

Answer (score 427, accepted):

`-L` returns true if the "file" exists and is a symbolic link (the linked file may or may not exist). You want `-f` (returns true if file exists and is a regular file) or maybe just `-e` (returns true if file exists regardless of type).

According to the [GNU manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test), `-h` is identical to `-L`, but according to the [BSD manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?test), it should not be used:

> `-h file`       True if file exists and is a symbolic link.  This operator is retained for compatibility with previous versions of this program. Do not rely on its existence; use -L instead.

Comment: I'm looking to see if a symlink DOESN'T exist. !-h or !-L should work for symlinks, !-e should work otherwise.

Comment: To help anyone who finds this via Google as I did, the full syntax using `!` is `if ! [ -L $mda ]; then .... fi`  i.e. put the exclamation mark _outside_ the square brackets.

Comment: Just wanted to add a little something to the tip given by @Sam; when doing these sorts of operations make sure to put your file name in quotes, to prevent issues with whitespaces.

e.g. `if [ ! -L "$mda" ]; then ... fi` (note: `if [ ! ... ]` and `if ! [ ... ]` are identical :)

Comment: do you really see a difference between -L and -h ? in my bash ( version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu ) man bash is identical for both -L and -h and they behave the same, ie they check that file actualy is a link and don't care whether the linked to file exists or not.

Comment: Yes, `-L` and `-h` are the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997666/difference-between-test-h-and-test-l). `man test` also confirms this.

Comment: Anybody has an idea how to check whether the **target file** exists?

Comment: @Sparhawk - any idea why they might be synonymous in the first place?  The best reason my googling came up with is "because it's bash"

Comment: @aaaaaa No idea… I thought I remembered some commands where `-h` was to do with symlinks, but I can't seem to find them now. `cp -H` is similar I guess, although mostly `-h` is to show the help. You should ask it as a question (perhaps in Unix/Linux)!

Comment: @aaaaaa `man test` on BSD's `test` provided some insight about `-h`: `This operator is retained for compatibility with previous versions of this program. Do not rely on its existence; use -L instead.` As for why they changed to `-L` over `-h`, I have no idea

Comment: @TomášZato `-e $(readlink -f $symlink)` would check if the linked file exists, but has the caveat that is also return true if `$symlink` exists but is not actually a symlink.

Comment: it seems if a link is broken, -e doesn't work but only -L can tell if the link exist (though the linked file doesn't exist). Is there anyway to test if a file/or even broken link exist ?

Comment: -f also return true if the file is a symbolic link and target is exist.

Comment: @dragonxlwang Just ran into a super annoying bug because of this. This detail should probably be added to the answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 108):

You can check the existence of a symlink and that it is not broken with:

```
[ -L ${my_link} ] && [ -e ${my_link} ]
```

So, the complete solution is:

```
if [ -L ${my_link} ] ; then
   if [ -e ${my_link} ] ; then
      echo "Good link"
   else
      echo "Broken link"
   fi
elif [ -e ${my_link} ] ; then
   echo "Not a link"
else
   echo "Missing"
fi
```

`-L` tests whether there is a symlink, broken or not. By combining with `-e` you can test whether the link is valid (links to a directory or file), not just whether it exists.

Comment: -L test if there is a symlink, broken or not. By combining with -e it is possible to test if the link is also valid (linking to a directory or file). Up-voting this solutions, since I find it important to capture this aspect.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm struggling with the logic behind if, this post really helped me ! +1

Comment: bash friendly: `if [[ -L "${my_link}" ]]; then` ...

Answer (score 40):

-L is the test for file exists and is **also** a symbolic link

If you do not want to test for the file being a symbolic link, but just test to see if it exists regardless of type (file, directory, socket etc) then use -e

So if file is really file and not just a symbolic link you can do all these tests and
get an exit status whose value indicates the error condition.

```
if [ ! \( -e "${file}" \) ]
then
     echo "%ERROR: file ${file} does not exist!" >&2
     exit 1
elif [ ! \( -f "${file}" \) ]
then
     echo "%ERROR: ${file} is not a file!" >&2
     exit 2
elif [ ! \( -r "${file}" \) ]
then
     echo "%ERROR: file ${file} is not readable!" >&2
     exit 3
elif [ ! \( -s "${file}" \) ]
then
     echo "%ERROR: file ${file} is empty!" >&2
     exit 4
fi
```

Comment: `-e "${file}"` fails if the symlink exists but its target does not exist.

Comment: Same result as Flimm. I'm on OS X. For me, -L and -h work for symlinks, but not -e or -f.

Comment: @Flimm, so if I just want to test if a filename is taken (whether it's a file or symlink without target existing) what's the best way to do it? apparently -e doesn't work

Comment: @dragonxlwang maybe `[ -L $file_or_link ] || [ -e $file_or_link ]`?

Answer (score 18):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To check if a file exist and is not a link.

Try this command:

```
file="/usr/mda" 
[ -f $file ] && [ ! -L $file ] && echo "$file exists and is not a symlink"
```

Answer (score 14):

How about using `readlink`?

```
# if symlink, readlink returns not empty string (the symlink target)
# if string is not empty, test exits w/ 0 (normal)
#
# if non symlink, readlink returns empty string
# if string is empty, test exits w/ 1 (error)
simlink? () {
  test "$(readlink "${1}")";
}

FILE=/usr/mda

if simlink? "${FILE}"; then
  echo $FILE is a symlink
else
  echo $FILE is not a symlink
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Is the file really a symbolic link?  If not, the usual test for existence is `-r` or `-e`.

See `man test`.

Answer (score 5):

1. first you can do with this style:

   ```
   mda="/usr/mda"
   if [ ! -L "${mda}" ]; then
     echo "=> File doesn't exist"
   fi
   ```
2. if you want to do it in more advanced style you can write it like below:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   mda="$1"
   if [ -e "$1" ]; then
       if [ ! -L "$1" ]
       then
           echo "you entry is not symlink"
       else
           echo "your entry is symlink"
       fi
   else
     echo "=> File doesn't exist"
   fi
   ```

the result of above is like:

```
root@linux:~# ./sym.sh /etc/passwd
you entry is not symlink
root@linux:~# ./sym.sh /usr/mda 
your entry is symlink
root@linux:~# ./sym.sh 
=> File doesn't exist
```

Comment: The first invocation is wrong if the file exists but is not a link, or is a dangling link.

The second is wrong if the path is a dangling symlink.

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing for file existence you want -e not -L. -L tests for a symlink.

Comment: I'm looking to see if a symlink DOESN'T exist. !-h or !-L should work for symlinks, !-e should work otherwise.

Comment: What you want is not clear. The file exists and is not a symlink? Then test *both* -e and !-h .