# how to check if the provided path is a symlink or a regular path

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am not a powere shell script programmer this is probably basic thnk but I need to know how can I check if the provided path is a symlink or a regular path  ?

I have a path /user/home/san/drive2

where drive2 is a symlink to

/drive at root level, so using what command in shell script I can check that the path is a symlink or regular path ?

Also, one can encounter, symlink at any path so how can we check recursively after each path separator whether it is a symlink or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if symlink exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767062/how-to-check-if-symlink-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look out the [lstat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function.

In this check  `st_mode` field: `S_ISLNK(m)`

Or you can do something like

```
if [ -L /path/to/file ]; then
  echo "is a symlink!"
else
  echo "not a symlink! maybe a directory or regular file, or does not exist"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readlink -f /user/home/san/drive2` to get the *canonical* path behind. That is, the actual path without any symlink. A corollary is that if the result of `readlink -f` is any different from the argument you've given to it, then there's a symlink somewhere in the original path.