# Bash -f check /sys/class/<device>/

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm trying to make script that monitor laptops (T480) batteries. There are 2 batteries, internal and external. Externals information seems to disappear `capacity` while it's charging.

`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`

**Problem**

I made check for the charging, if the file exists, problem is that it pass the `-f` on missing `capacity`, it's `ASCII text` so it shouldn't be a problem.

**Script**

I've tried `-e` `-d` `-c` too, but no success.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
...

[[ -f /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity ]] && {
    EXTERNAL="$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)" 
   ...some logic
}
..
```

Comment: Maybe you can try making a second check to see if the file is not empty, like this: ```[[ $(du your_file | cut -f 1) > 0 ]]``` or more easily, with ```[[ -s your_file ]] ```

Comment: `-s` check If file exists and its size is greater than zero, it's ok if it's empty, my goal is to avoid logic on non existing file after `-f` check.

Comment: It's really difficult to reproduce this. Are you sure that the file actually disappears? Make sure that you are not creating the file again in a previous command in your script

Comment: `/sys/class/` contains every device class registered with the kernel, I don't write to any of these files, I just read the output.

Comment: `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` is a syslink. Maybe consider checking if [the syslink is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767062/how-to-check-if-a-symlink-exists) before checking the file inside it.

Comment: thank you very much `-L` check works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Converting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466907/bash-f-check-sys-class-device?noredirect=1#comment119254203_67466907) to an answer</sup>

---

`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` is a symlink, as shown by the output of `ls -lta`:

```sh
root@deb:~# cd /sys/class/power_supply/
root@deb:/sys/class/power_supply# ls -tla
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 21 14:02 BAT0 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 21 14:02 ADP0 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP0
drwxr-xr-x 48 root root 0 May 21 14:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 May 21 14:02 .
root@deb:/sys/class/power_supply#
```

<sup>[Obnoxious screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bUaA.png)</sup>

Instead of using the `-f` flag which:

> True if file exists and is a **regular file**.

Since you're dealing with a symlink, I'd recommend `-L` flag which

> True if file exists and is a **symbolic link**.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)